# C# function overload with different parameters resulting in "Type already defines a member called 'IIN' with the same parameter types"

Tags: c#, lambda, overloading

I have a static function (in a static utility class), thus:

```
public static bool IIN(object oValue, params object[] oValues)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i <= oValues.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
        if ((oValue.ToString()) == (oValues[i].ToString())) return true;

    return false;
}
```

This enables me to supply a list of values to check if the first parameter matches any of the rest, similar to the TSQL `IN` keyword.

I have a class in another assembly that uses it an awful lot, with some fairly complex conditions, so I've wanted to be able to declare a named Lambda function at the top of the class that points to it in another assembly, simply for brevity and readibility, so that instead of having:

`Core.CoreHelper.IIN(a, "fred", "jim", "sheila")` etc

I can just have:

`IIN(a, "fred", "jim", "sheila")` and so on

However, Lambda doesn't appear to be able to handle param arrays (i.e. declared with params). So, I tried creating several Lambda functions with the same name and a varying number of parameters, thus:

```
private static Func<string, string, string, bool> IIN = (s, s1, s2) => Core.CoreHelper.IIN(s, s1, s2);
private static Func<string, string, string, string, bool> IIN = (s, s1, s2, s3) => Core.CoreHelper.IIN(s, s1, s2, s3);
```

etc

...but Lambda doesn't handle Lambda function overloads. Fair enough. So my last attempt is to function overload the IIN function itself and change the `params array` to an `object[]` and declare a second instance of IIN:

```
public static bool IIN(object oValue, object[] oValues)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i <= oValues.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
        if ((oValue.ToString()) == (oValues[i].ToString())) return true;

    return false;
}
```

so I can call IIN in one of two ways:

```
if (IIN(a, "fred", "jim", "sheila")) ...
if (IIN(a, new [] {"fred", "jim", "sheila"})) ...
```

But, I'm getting an error with the two declarations of IIN, which is: `Type 'CoreHelper' already defines a member called 'IIN' with the same parameter types`. I kind of get why it looks like it is overloading with the same pattern of parameters, but also not. They are different declarations, as one is a `params` parameter.

My IIN function in my Core assembly is used my many other projects and assemblies, some in production. It's not really a goer to change them all.

Is there a way I can achieve this without breaking backwards compatability? As a preference, I'd simply like to be able to point a named Lambda function at a function declared with `params` in general.

Comment: It seems to me that this could be solved a lot more easily with `using static Core.CoreHelper;`

Comment: And possibly `global using static Core.CoreHelper;` if it's used as broadly as you say.

Comment: @madreflection - you are absolutely right and I had no idea that that was possible. Thank you, kind sir/maam. If you'd like to put that as an answer I'll mark it so when the time limit pings.

Comment: There are plenty of similar questions already on the site that have this answer. Please accept this duplicate suggestion in lieu of duplicating those answers.

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319226/can-i-import-a-static-class-as-a-namespace-to-call-its-methods-without-specifyin

Comment: Note the way to handle this type of function overloading is to have the methods with 1, 2, 3 and so on inputs up to n and then have one with n inputs and a params array after that to handle n+1.